# visual studio 2015 debug in chrome opens new window then nothing

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I don't really know how this happened but after a restart on my company computer which updated the antivirus program, every time I press F5 to debug in Chrome, all it does is open a new window, then does nothing. I read this thing sort of happens in 2017 but I'm using VS 2015 professional

Whats odd is that, when I debug in IE Edge & 11, Firefox and Opera, it creates a new tab and actually opens the site. In Chrome it just opens a NEW WINDOW, then nothing. Ideas anyone?

Comment: If you're going to downvote, you can at least tell me why. If it sounds like a strange question thats because i've never seen it before and I am trying to figure out why only chrome has this issue. There isn't much more detail I can give, I press F5, it starts the debugger, VS opens a new window in chrome, then, nothing, all I have is a new window but the site isn't showing.

Comment: Which Chrome version did you use? I debug a web site project using the Chrome Version 59.0.3071.86 with VS2015, it works well in my side, please clean up the cache/history, and then update your browser to the latest version, debug it again. In addition, just run your site with "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)", does it work normally?

Comment: I'm using the latest and greatest version of Chrome, I cleared cache/history, closed down VS, opened it back up, pressed F5 to debug, and still the same behaviour. Just for kicks I tried Ctrl + F5, and same behaviour. If I debug it to work on a different browser, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If it still has this issue without debugging and other browser works well using the same web site project, I feel that it would be not the debugger tool issue.

We would think about the browser itself. If possible, please reset your VS settings, and then create a new default web site project, not add any breakpoint, debug it again after you set the Chrome as the default browser. If still no help, I suggest you uninstall and re-install this browser. Of course, please also close all third party tools in your windows.

Update:

Based on our discussions, it would be related to your Windows Environment or the browser itself, I agree with you, use other browser like Opera as your browser in debug would be a better workaround now if you could re-install your windows now. Have a nice day:)

Comment: When I debug in Chrome with any other web project, it behaves the same way. I will try uninstalling chrome and reinstalling it to see if it fixes the problem

Comment: @Alex W, If a simple app still has this issue, it would be related to the browser itself. I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: I've been looking for that "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome and IE)" option but I can't find it. Ended up uninstalling chrome, funny thing is, it didn't quite uninstall properly and when I went to install it again, it just installed after it finished downloading. I think something on my computer, really messed up chrome. You mentioned "reset your VS settings", how do I do that?

Comment: @Alex W, It was the VS2017 new option, just ignore it. If you want to reset your VS, TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->select “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings”->Choose a Default Collection of settings. Check it again. But if you get the setup issue for the Chrome, I feel that it was related to your Windows Environment or chrome itself, not the real VS or debugging tool issue.

Comment: yeah I'm beginning to suspect the issue is my computer but its a work computer theres only so much I can do plus its not really my area of expertise.

Comment: @Alex W, If so, maybe using other browser as the default browser would be a better workaround for you now, of course, as our previous discussions, if still no help, suggest you post this issue to the Chrome official supported site:)

Comment: Yeah I think I may have to bug we were having issues throughout the company and there is a fix which may or maynot fix my chrome issue. I highly doubt it but once that "fix" is in place and if I still see the same issues then I will make a post in the chrome support forum. For now I'm using Opera as my browser in debug, then double checking that it works in Chrome later on, usually is the other way around. Its annoying but it works

Comment: @Alex W, If so, I will close this case temporarily, if you get any latest information or better answer, feel free to share it here:)

Comment: For the foreseeable future i will stick with the Opera work around. Close this if necessary

Comment: @Jack Zhai, No it's not his Windows Environment, because I have the **exact** same problem and I also tried the "Reset Settings" but didn't work. I'm running Windows Server 2016 Standard and VS2015 Update 3 on a HyperV VM. Any ideas? Please Note that I didn't try re-installation of Chrome, because when I try to **start Chrome first and then Run/Debug from VS then it runs OK**. By the way, with IE 11, it runs OK too, no probs.